# Error at prompt:Setting Up Greenplum command center web Application with centos 6.5

Tags: greenplum

We have small gpdb cluster . In that,We are trying to setup  the Greenplum command center web portal.

**ENVIRONMENT IS**

Product  |  Version

Pivotal Greenplum (GPDB)    4.3.x

Pivotal Greenplum Command Center (GPCC) 2.2

stage of error is :  Set up the Greenplum Command Center Console

We have launched the following  setup utility.

that is

**$ gpcmdr --setup**

Getting the following error  at prompt msg :

```
What is the hostname of the standby master host? [smdw]:sbhostname
standby is sbhostname

Done writing lighttpd configuration to /usr/local/greenplum-cc-web/./instances/gpcc/conf/lighttpd.conf
Done writing web UI configuration to /usr/local/greenplum-cc-web/./instances/gpcc/conf/gpperfmonui.conf
Done writing web UI clustrs configuration to /usr/local/greenplum-cc-web/./instances/gpcc/conf/clusters.conf

Copying instance 'gpcc' to host 'sbhostname'...
ERROR: the instance directory was not successfuly copied to the remote host: '/usr/local/greenplum-cc-web/./instances/gpcc'
```

Comment: Check whether your user has write access to `/usr/local` on `sbhostname`, most likely this is the problem

Comment: Checked it has permission  777  to user

Comment: rerun the installation in verbose mode. Check that there is enough space there and the `sbhostname` is available for passwordless SSH from the master node. If this won't help, raise support ticket

Comment: We have just checked that  sbhostname is available for passwordless SSH from the master node. [gpadmin@mdw ~]$ ssh sbhostname
Last login: Mon May 23 09:08:20 2016 from mdw
[gpadmin@sbhostname ~]$

Comment: At this moment we have skipped the  standby process . we have launched the web portal . Next concern it is  not allowing me to enter by using  username and password.  trying all way to enter into the site.

Answer (score 1):

+You have to reload the configuration by `gpstop -u` or restart the the database after the gpcc setup, Because setup will add some entries in `pg_hba.conf` for gpperfmon.

+Also check if you have correct entries in `.pgpass` file in `/home/gpadmin`

Comment: Checked  the loading of pg_hba.conf  using gpstop -u. then  checked .pgpass  also . Here is my  pg_hba.conf looks like http://paste.ofcode.org/yF5QcAZEif9PRJuWwuimWK

Comment: Also When i  am trying to  use .pgpass   credential it is  saying error to communicate with server  here is my  .pgpass content http://paste.ofcode.org/KWJCXbaWR9kpkFwwJyNRgT

Comment: Here is Complete Log  for not communicating to server from  ./pg_log :http://paste.ofcode.org/NdJ5wPpCeERxrPC88UpwVX

Comment: When i am tryin to  start the instance that is  $gpcmdr --start . getting following messege at output console .http://paste.ofcode.org/MxLZ4stVY2ZuVpbFYKFyjz

Comment: We have resolved the issue by making ::1 entry in pg_hba.conf.